# How to intercept component loading with a loader plugin in aurelia (jspm)?

Tags: aurelia, jspm, aurelia-loader

I want to intercept the module loading of Aurelia to redirect some calls.

To do such things the aurelia-loader has a `addPlugin()` interface. You add a suffix like `!myplugin` to a resource to mark that it should be loaded using that plugin.

Now when I do this with my own component, it loads the JS file but the name for the HTML template is messed up. Like from the resource name *my-comp!myplugin* it will load *my-comp.js* but tries to find *my-comp!myplugin.html* which does not match the plugin name anymore.

I have provided a gist with that issue here: https://gist.run/?id=c7ed477bc652540ed8b0702d843f1832

The loader plugin code in **main.js** is basically:

```
loader.addPlugin('gate', {
  fetch(address) {
    console.info('Intercepted:', address);
    var tmpParts = address.split('.');
    var extension = tmpParts[tmpParts.length - 1].toLowerCase();
    if (extension == 'css') {
      console.debug('Loading as styles', address);
      return loader.loadText(address);
    } else if(extension == 'html') {
      console.debug('Loading as template:', address);
      return loader.loadTemplate(address);
    } else {
      console.debug('Loading as module:', address);
      return loader.loadModule(address);
    }
  }
});
```

Using it like this in a template (marked with *Issue 1* in the gist):

```
<require from="./comp2!gate"></require>
```

After that is should be possible to load the component like this:

```
<comp2></comp2>
```

Or even like this:

```
<compose view-model="./comp2!gate"></compose>
```

Instead the name for the template is messed up, the browser console says:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
>
> https://gist.host/run/1485182959149/comp2!gate.html

The expected name of the template would be `https://gist.host/run/1485182959149/comp2.html!gate` (including the plugin)

How can I fix the loader plugin to work correctly?

The loader is `aurelia-loader-default` 1.0.0, JSPM is 0.16.39, Node is 6.5.0, NPM 3.10.5.

---

I have added a second gist.run: https://gist.run/?id=1ddd4233e3afc40d89eb64b751e1dd8f

It is a bit shorter. When I specify the view using `@useView` decorator in `comp2.js` (marked with *issue 4*), it works - but I cannot specify a loader plugin with `@useView`. I would expect it to load the view with the same loader plugin or be able to specify a loader plugin with `@useView`.

---

Okay, I found a solution which looks like it can work with less code and patching and it works between two gists.

This gist contains the external component `comp3`:
https://gist.run/?id=dc837978a514011e13c872dbad92ae3f

This gist is the basic Aurelia app with a plugin and a small patch to the `applyPluginToUrl` method of the loader:
https://gist.run/?id=39e6fdacefc9e5c69b42a5e8c9049384

If the gist URLs are fixed, it should work for everyone. The Aurelia app loads `comp3` from the first gist and displays it (you see the purple border define in the comp3-view).

There is one caveat at the moment: No support for CSS as SystemJS adds the extension `.js` to them, looks like I have to take care of that.

I do not like the path to `loader.applyPluginToUrl` but SystemJS does not really support plugin chaining and so the order must be correct. Also this solution requires all external components to set `@useView` including the loader plugin.

Any better approaches?